# Why does form action call not keep input file when using back button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

```
function validate_form()
{
        //..... validation and other stuff will go here ...
}
<form name="read" id="read" action="test2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate_form();">
    <input type="file" name="pac" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In the above example, if you hit the browser back button, the input file remains.

```
function validate_form()
{
    //..... validation and other stuff will go here ...
    document.read.action = "test2.php"; 
}
<form name="read" id="read" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate_form(this);">
    <input type="file" name="pac" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In the above example, if you hit the browser back button, the input file is cleared. Why is that? Is the only way to get around this is to save the input into a cookie or session variable? If so, not sure how to save a file.

I have a reason to use the call from JS. I removed most of the code for the above examples. This is happening under Chrome and Firefox. Didn't test others.

Comment: That's just the way browsers work. For security reasons, I doubt there is any work-around to that.

Comment: But it does work when using action in form. Just curious why it does not work when calling from JS. Some background… I will be compiling this using ExeOutput, which has a clean way to go back and redo an input. It’s always nice to have previous inputs remain.